# How can a US citizen born in US get a copy of their birth certificate from abroad?

Tags: us-citizens, birth-certificate

How can a US citizen access an official copy of their birth certificate (born pre-computer era) while living outside of the US? Is there an on-line service? Can a proxy living in the US access it?

Answer (score 2):

Birth certificates are issued by the states, and each state's procedures are different. I believe in most states you can order by mail, but I am not sure if they will mail the certificate to a foreign address; you may have to pay more or provide an appropriately stamped envelope.